# Get job number from non-interactive queuing of "at" job

Tags: linux, bash, scheduled-tasks, at-command

---

## Background

I'm writing a script that occasionally queues jobs via the `at` command. In order to accomplish this in an automated, non-interactive way, I `echo` the commands to be executed to a file, i.e.:

```
echo "ls -la" > cmd.txt
```

I then schedule the command to run 2 minutes later via:

```
at -f cmd.txt now + 2 min
```

---

## Problem

I would like to, in an automated, non-interactive, deterministic way; determine the job number associated with the task my script just queued up. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be anything supplied in the return code (i.e. `echo $?`), nor a CLI command I can issue, that provides me with this. I can always scrape the `stdout` data, i.e.:

`$> A=$(at -f cmd.txt now + 1 min)`
`warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh`
***`job 6`*** `at Fri Mar  8 07:18:00 2019`

However, I would like to, if possible, use something more canonical/direct than parsing the `stdout` data, as I want to avoid cases where the `stdout` varies from one platform to the next (i.e. Linux, BSD, OSX).

---

## Question

How can I directly acquire the job number (in a script) for an `at` job my script just queued up?

---

## Edit

I have to account for other processes also using the `at` command concurrently.

Comment: "I have to account for other processes also using the at command concurrently." Those processes are added by the same user? You are, or are not, running this as root? Can other processes, or your process, use a dedicated queue? (Eg, `at -q c ...`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record the `at` queue state before scheduling, schedule your job, then find the additions:

```
$ date
Fri Mar  8 10:33:34 EST 2019
$ atq
3   2019-03-08 10:34 a bishop
$ atq > atq.1
$ echo "ls -l" > cmd.txt
$ at -f cmd.txt now + 2 min
job 4 at 2019-03-08 10:36
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/bishop
$ atq > atq.2
$ comm atq.1 atq.2
3   2019-03-08 10:34 a bishop
    4   2019-03-08 10:36 a bishop
$ comm -23 atq.1 atq.2 | awk '{print $1}' # completed jobs
3
$ comm -13 atq.1 atq.2 | awk '{print $1}' # added jobs
4
```

As demonstrated, this is impervious to jobs finishing under you. Of course, if jobs are added in separate processes simultaneously, and you want to exclude those, a different solution would be called for (perhaps by grepping for the user submitting the job, or having different processes submit into separate `at -q` queues).

Comment: I added a CLI application I wrote in about 20 lines of C++ and boost to use a dedicated "named mutex" to restrict access to this script. With it plus your example, all's well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could use `atq` to see the jobs queue after each submission, and get the job ID from the first column of the last line for any newly submitted job.